# Registration plugin custom fields - Always required?

Tags: facebook, registration, custom-fields, required

Is there any way using the facebook registration plugin custom fields, to make them NOT required? I have a "Company" and "Address 2" field that I want to make optional, however, they always seem to be required. Here is the code I am using within the iframe:

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
        client_id=MY_APP_ID&
        redirect_uri=MY_CALLBACK_URL&
        fields=[
                { 'name':'name' },
                { 'name':'first_name' },
                { 'name':'last_name' },
                { 'name':'company', 'description':'Company Name', 'type':'text' },
                { 'name':'email' },
                { 'name':'phone', 'description':'Phone Number', 'type':'text' },
                { 'name':'address1', 'description':'Address', 'type':'text' },
                { 'name':'city', 'description':'City', 'type':'text' },
                { 'name':'state', 'description':'State/Region', 'type':'text' },
                { 'name':'zip', 'description':'Zip Code', 'type':'text' }
                ]"
        scrolling="auto"
        frameborder="no"
        style="border:none"
        allowTransparency="true"
        width="100%"
        height="600">
</iframe>
```

If I leave any of the fields blank, it returns that the fields must be filled in. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare optional fields with no_submit flag and then do something with values using onvalidate function, i.e. save to cookie or send via Ajax to your server.

look at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/ and goto no_submit

its not easily done but do able